# What is Var(X/Y) if X and Y follow log normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

What is $Var(X/Y)$ if $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$ are known and if $X$ and $Y$ follow **log normal distribution**?

Comment: Are they independent? Do they have the same log-normal distribution?

Comment: they have different log normal distributions. They are correlated.